# java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial

Tags: android-studio, android-asynctask

I am trying write data in mysql (wamp server) using android app. It was working perfectly.

Now it shows follwoing error:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: **get/set setting for
>   user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0;** this
>   requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
>
> at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:15168)
>               at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2498)
>               at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.call(SettingsProvider.java:688)
>               at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:325)
>               at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:275)
>               at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

I am using android-studio, windows 7, 32 bit.

Can you please help me to solve this.